# EDA Playground $dumpfile: No *.vcd file found

Tags: verilog, edaplayground

I am having trouble getting some code to run in EDA Playground. I keep getting the message:

> No *.vcd file found. EPWave will not open. Did you use
> '$dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars;'?

But, I have it included in the code.

Here's the link:

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2pim

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code does not compile. (There is an error because your design has no port called `state`.) So, your simulation does not run and so there will be no `dump.vcd` file.